# How to get the system settings in iPhone for 3G or data roaming status

Tags: iphone

I need to determine if certain system settings have been set on the iPhone. i.e. Whether or not 3G or data roaming are enabled/disabled. Is it possible to read the system settings, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Some are readable; some are not. The data roaming option is, AFAIK, not available to developers to either get or set. If you want to see this added, I would recommend you contact Apple via the [Bug Reporter](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) utility and file an enhancement request.